# Can I travel to Finland indirectly given the current U.K. travel ban?

Tags: uk, air-travel, covid-19, borders, finland

I wanted to ask if anyone would know if it is permissible for me to travel to Helsinki from the U.K. indirectly given the current travel ban on direct flights from U.K. to Finland? My travel would be regarded as essential in the sense that I have an employment contract for work and residence certificate from immigration in Finland.

For example, I was wondering if I could in principle travel from the U.K. to Amsterdam and then from Amsterdam to Helsinki? My worry is if I am allowed to do this given the current Dutch border control covid restrictions (or other similar restrictions in alternate transiting countries)?  That is, it is not clear to me whether I need an employment contract/ residence permit also in the transiting country?

Thanks in advance for any comments!

Answer (score 1):

For transit at Amsterdam you need a negative PCR test (Antigen won't do, unlike for e.g. France or Germany), but other than that no problem.

Comment: Interesting. So I would not need an employment contract or anything? I’m just worried in case I get turned away at the border... maybe I will confirm with the relevant transient border anyway by email. Thanks!

Comment: @CAF Are you an EU/Schengen/UK citizen, or have a residence permit there? If so none of that is needed, only for Finland. You could email border control though. As examples, for Amsterdam airport it's hoofd.doorlaatpost.gb@mindef.nl, for Frankfurt airport bpold.frankfurt@polizei.bund.de

Comment: Thanks very much. Yes I am a U.K. citizen. So I would need some negative test to proceed through the border control and I guess they would need evidence that I am indeed only transiting through Amsterdam and that I have an employment contract in Finland.

Comment: @CAF Only the test and connecting boarding pass (and if it's like at Frankfurt, the test isn't checked at border control, but as a special check outside the plane by border officers)

Comment: @CAF UPDATE: if travelling from the UK you now need an advance PCR test AND an antigen test at the airport (£50) on the day of departure.

Comment: @Crazydre This info should be edited into your Answer.